# C# - How can I call a method from another 'class ClassName<T> where T : IComparable'

Tags: c#, methods, call, binary-tree, icomparable

In my 'Program.cs' I am trying to call method 'inOrder()' from another class 'BinTree.cs'.

Class BinTree starts with `class BinTree<T> where T : IComparable`

I've tried:

```
inOrder();
```

and

```
BinTree<T>.inOrder();
```

and

```
BinTree<int>.inOrder();
```

But none of these work.

Thanks for looking.

EDIT:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node<int> tree = new Node<int>(6);
        tree.Left = new Node<int>(2);
        tree.Left.Right = new Node<int>(5);

        tree.Left.Right.Data = 3;

        tree.Right = new Node<int>(8);



        (new BinTree<int>()).inOrder();

    }
```

EDIT2:

```
    private Node<T> root;
    public BinTree()  //creates an empty tree
    {
        root = null;
    }
    public BinTree(Node<T> node)  //creates a tree with node as the root
    {
        root = node;
    }
```

Comment: _how_ and _where_ `inOrder()` declared ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094232/generics-and-implementing-icomparable

Comment: If `inOrder` is an instance method, you need to create an instance first.  If it's static, it needs to be public, in which case `BinTree<int>.inOrder();` should work.

Comment: 'inOrder()' is declared in class BinTree<T>. 'public void inOrder()
        {
            inOrder(root);
        }'

Comment: Sorry not sure how to use code tags in the comments section

Comment: Ok.  So call it with `(new BinTree<int>()).inOrder();`

Comment: inOrder is indeed public but it is not static

Comment: Yes, which means you need to call it off an instance.

Comment: Hmm that runs but now it is not using my tree which I'll post the code for above.

Comment: Do you have some sort of mechanism to add `Node<T>` objects to a `BinTree<T>` instance?

Comment: EDIT2 in top post. I'm new to all this so bare with me sorry.

Comment: Ok starting to make sense now.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you need to create a `BinTree<int>` instance and pass in your `Node<int>` instance on the constructor.  Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create Node instances for tree
        Node<int> node = new Node<int>(6);
        node.Left = new Node<int>(2);
        node.Left.Right = new Node<int>(5);
        node.Left.Right.Data = 3;
        node.Right = new Node<int>(8);

        // Create tree, set root node
        BinTree<int> tree = new BinTree<int>(node);
        tree.inOrder(); // Call inOrder method of tree instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you. Now I'll try and figure out why because my assigned work just says 'the user would call 'tree.inOrder();'.